# Is there an equivalent to the Christian charismatic movement in Islam?

Tags: christianity, comparative-religions, spirituality

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charismatic_movement):

> The **charismatic movement** is the international trend of historically mainstream Christian congregations adopting beliefs and practices similar to Pentecostalism. Fundamental to the movement is the use of spiritual gifts (charismata).
>
> Among Anglicans, the charismatic movement emerged in 1958; it reached Lutherans and Presbyterians in 1962. Among Roman Catholics, it spread around 1967. Methodists became involved in the charismatic movement in the 1970s.

In my own words, the charismatic movement emphasizes "spiritual gifts" (such as healing, prophecy, speaking in tongues, etc. -- see [1 Corinthians 12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2012&version=NIV) for a more exhaustive list) and "ecstatic/mystical experiences" (such as the [baptism with the Holy Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptism_with_the_Holy_Spirit)). In more extreme congregations, people may even display very extreme and odd behaviors, such as [shaking or trembling violently](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/25631/is-there-a-scientific-explanation-for-dramatic-body-shaking-and-trembling-in-rel), [behaving like animals](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79576/are-there-any-records-of-animal-like-behaviors-outside-the-toronto-blessing), etc.

Is there anything like this in  Islam?

Answer (score 0):

The Charismatic practice is very particular to Christians. You will find most similarities in [Sufi Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufism) concerning spirituality. Searching contract to the Spirit of the Most High and healing through prayer or [dhikr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhikr) is also found there. But speaking tongues or prophecies is not Islamic practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Turkish have dervish . They whirl and recite Allahs names in order to establish closeness to Allah .

There is also certain Sufi practices that recite and sing Allahs names in order to achieve certain bond and closeness.

However let’s make it clear Quran clearly states how to achieve closeness to Allah and that is by submission to will of Allah and that is by following Quran and commandments.

You don’t need to do this extra ways of achieving closeness . It is obligatory Muslim to pray 5 times a day which is very peaceful and satisfying practice.

I hope this answers your question